# How to locate a file whose name (almost) matches its containing directory

Tags: bash

I am trying to write a script to run under Jenkins on a remote server that will exercise our system. The system can import files in different formats that are distinguished by their extensions. We have test data in various formats that is located in subdirectories of `resources` thus we have

```
resources/datasetA/datasetA.format1
resources/datasetB/datasetB.format1
resources/datasetC/datasetC.format2
etc.
```

In general there are other files in the dataset directories and additonal subdirectories.

I'm trying to pick out the import source files - those listed above - but having no luck.

My original idea was

```
for dir in $(ls -d resources/*/)
do
    dataset=$(echo ${dir%/} | xargs basename)
    source=$(ls resources/$dataset/$dataset.*)
    .
    .
    .
done
```

This works fine when I type it into a cygwin window on my local machine, but fails on the remote machine where `ls resources/$dataset/$dataset.*` appears to return several files. The directory contents are identical on the local and remote machines and I don't understand why this should happen.

I then tried to list all the files in resources/$dataset and identify the last one that where the basename less extension matches $dataset, something like

```
for dir in $(ls -d resources/*/)
do
    dataset=$(echo ${dir%/} | xargs basename)
    find resources/$dataset -maxdepth 1 -type f | while read fnm
    do
        baseFnm=$(basename $fnm)
        if [ ${baseFnm%.*} = $dataset ]
        then
            source=$fnm
        fi
    done
    # Exercise the system using $source
done
```

but `source` is empty when I try to use it. I was highly confused by this since I could add trace within the `if` structure and see that the test was succeeding.

Nothing daunted, I tried to break out of the loop if the test succeeded but in this case `fnm` was empty.

Help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general if is a bad idea to attempt to parse the output of `ls`.

Perhaps the following will help?

```
for d in resources/*/
do
    rn=${d%/};rn=${rn##*/}
    for f in "$d$rn."*
    do
       [ -f "$f" ] && printf '%s\n' "$f"
    done
done
```

You mention that you are using jenkins and a remote machine. The most likely reason for your issues are a lack of quoting, particularly of dollar signs. How are you invoking this script?

Comment: Thanks. That works a treat. I have come to shell scripting late in life and struggle to know whether expansion of * happens in the shell or in utilities like ls. I like the approach of "work out what you're looking for and see if it's there" rather than "see what's there and check whether it's what you want". To answer your question, I'm typing the script into a "build step" definition in the Jenkins configuration of the build.

Comment: In general the shell will do the expansion of wildcards. The historical behavior of the shell if there is no match of the wildcard is to pass the pattern unchanged to the program.